# Need to refresh the page to show highchart using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using a simple site to show my statistics using Highcharts and jQuery Mobile.
The problem is, the first time the page is loaded, no chart is displayed. I need to reload the page by hand to show the charts.

I have checked all the proposed solutions (based primarily on change the order of scripts loading, delegate functions on each page creation, put scripts on data-role="page") but nothing works for me.

I am using django templates and this is how my page looks like now (after thousand unsuccessful changes):

```
{% extends "web/dashboard_base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/highcharts/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/ipki_charts.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  {% for indicator in indicators %}
  values_per_indicator_manager({{ indicator.id }}, '{{ indicator.id }}_container');
  {% endfor %}
});
</script>

<ul data-role="listview">
  {% for indicator in indicators %}
  <li><h2 style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
      {{ indicator }} 
      ({{ indicator.unit }})</h2>
  <div id="{{ indicator.id }}_container"
       style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto">
  </div>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
...
```

function 'values_per_indicator_manager' loads data using ajax and creates the Chart. You can take a look at ipki_charts.js here:
http://pastebin.com/MMQ3V1hD

Comment: Any console errors? Also, where is loaded jQuery mobile?

Comment: jQuery mobile is loaded at the end, just before </body>. I've placed at other places, but I read somewhere that it has to be placed at the end to not interfere highcharts. But, you know, does not work. No console errors either.

Comment: Can you point to this where this is written about jQuery mobile? As I know, Highcharts requires jQuery to work, so if is not loaded Highcharts won't work.

Comment: I am loading all of that in this order: jquery - jqueryui - highcharts - jquerymobile. Indeed, all is working when I reload. The problem as far as I know is that the jQuery Mobile page is created after highcharts generates the object, or something like that. But I don't know how to resolve that.

Comment: Have your read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532022/jquery-mobile-and-highcharts-integration)? For sure container for Highcharts (renderTo) have to be in DOM to create Highcharts chart.

Comment: Yeap. I did read it. It is working (or it looks like it is working) by changing anchor previous to this page, adding `data-ajax=false`.